# Allegro 4 text output

Tags: c++, file-io, allegro

I'm trying to display the text contained in a text file using Allegro 4, I have no trouble doing it while on the console on C++, but when I try to switch from cout<< to textprintf I get some errors, here's the code of the part I have trouble with:

```
do{
    char c;
    c=archivo.get();
    textprintf(screen,font,300,300,15,"%s,%d",c,1);
}while(!archivo.eof());     
system("pause");
archivo.close();
```

Comment: What are your errors you get?

Comment: I didn't put this in the question, sorry =/. But the error is that when the text is displayed on the screen it doesn't recognize the end of line of the file, instead it just prints: "^"

Comment: I believe the correct call to the function you're looking for is textprintf_ex